# Autoform insert Sum of fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Is it possible (and how) with Meteor and AutoForm to insert in database Sum field that depend on other fields in same form, and Sum field to be hidden, example orderSum filed.

**orderSum** = orderLength + orderLayers

file.js

```
Order = new Meteor.Collection("order", {
  schema: {
  'orderLayers': {
        type: Number,
        label: "Layers",
        optional: false,
        decimal: true, 
        min: 0
    },
    'orderLength': {
        type: Number,
        label: "Length",
        optional: false,    
        decimal: true, 
        min: 0
    }
}
});
```

file.html

```
{{> quickForm collection="Order" id="insertOrderForm" type='insert' buttonContent="Add Order"}}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display only some of the fields from SimpleSchema then use option `fields`:

```
<template name="form">
    {{> quickForm fields='orderLayers,orderLength' collection="Order" id="insertOrderForm" type='insert' buttonContent="Add Order"}}
</template>
```

If you want to do some calculations on field `orderLayers` and `orderLength` then use `autoValue` option in new field `orderSum`

```
Order = new Meteor.Collection("order", {
    schema: {
        'orderLayers': {
            type: Number,
            label: "Layers",
            optional: false,
            decimal: true,
            min: 0
        },
        'orderLength': {
            type: Number,
            label: "Length",
            optional: false,
            decimal: true,
            min: 0
        },
        'orderSum': {
            type: Number,
            optional: false,
            decimal: true,
            autoValue:function(){
                var result = this.siblingField("orderLength").value +this.siblingField("orderLayers").value;
                console.log(result);
                return result
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to test above quickly then clone:
https://github.com/parhelium/meteor-so-autoform-autovalue-fields

Comment: is `siblingField` deprecated? Can't use it. `this` just returns `{name: "name.$.name"}`